# I need to use PHP after a confirmation from JavaScript, some sites said to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need some help with AJAX , people need to confirm if they want to buy something , and if they confirmed , they buy it , when they decline they don't buy it, my first opinion was to use php in JavaScript, because after some googling I founded out I needed AJAX for that , but I am a total stranger with AJAX , so can somebody help me with this?? my JavaScript :

```
<input type="submit" name="versturen" value="Aankopen" action="versturen" onclick="myFunction();return true;" >
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to buy this??!");
    if (r==true){
    }
}
</script>
```

my php :

```
if (isset($_POST['Levering']) && $_POST['Levering'] == 'Ja') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bestelling(Naam, Adres, Telefoon, Email, Bestelling, Levering) VALUES ('$Naam','$Adres','$Telefoon','$Email','$Bestelling1','1')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('query fout');
    if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
    } else {
        $to = "titansafes@telenet.be";
        $subject = "Bestelling";
        $message = "De volgende persoon : $Naam \n Heeft besteld: $Bestelling1 \n Gegevens: \n Adres: $Adres \n Telefoon nummer : $Telefoon \n E-mail : $Email  \n Deze persoon zou graag zijn kluis geleverd zien.  ";
        $from = "$Email";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "<script>alert('Uw bestelling is geplaatst , klik op home als u weg wilt gaan.');</script>";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['Levering']) && $_POST['Levering'] == 'Nee') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bestelling(Naam, Adres, Telefoon, Email, Bestelling, Levering) VALUES ('$Naam','$Adres','$Telefoon','$Email','$Bestelling1','0')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('query fout');
    if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
    } else {
        $to = "titansafes@telenet.be";
        $subject = "Bestelling";
        $message = "De volgende persoon : $Naam \n Heeft besteld: $Bestelling1 \n Gegevens: \n Adres: $Adres \n Telefoon nummer : $Telefoon \n E-mail : $Email \n Deze persoon zou graag zijn kluis komen afhalen.  ";
        $from = "$Email";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "<script>alert('Uw bestelling is geplaatst , klik op home als u weg wilt gaan.');</script>";
    }
}
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('query fout');
if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
} else {
    $to = "$Email";
    $subject = "Bestelling";
    $message = "Beste klant \n U heeft een bestelling geplaatst op titansafes. U wordt binnenkort gecontacteerd over uw bestelling ($Bestelling1). \n Met vriendelijke Groeten \n Titansafes";
    $from = "titansafes@telenet.be";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

PS : The language is dutch , dont mind that :D

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ :-)

Comment: But I don't get how to use it , and I don't have time to study it, and I don't know how to put my code , in the way I like it into AJAX , with that ...

Comment: w3schools is a bad source. 
@Bondjens if you do not have time to study/learn it. What did you expect this is not a code fixing service.

Comment: If you can't find time to study something, you'll never be able to use it the way you like it... :-) If you don't like w3schools tutorial, search here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/ ...

Comment: Here you go: in your own language [a site to study](http://netters.nl/artikelen/ajax/ajax-voor-beginners/). It's raining, so you have all weekend.

Comment: no time to learn -> hire somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have

> ```
> <input type="submit" name="versturen" value="Aankopen" action="versturen" onclick="myFunction();return true;" >
> ```

change to

> ```
> <input type="submit" name="versturen" value="Aankopen" action="versturen" onclick="return myFunction();" >
> ```

and add to your javascript `return true;` and `return false;` in the if-statement.

Another part is you have to protect you system against sql-injections with using the pdo or some other stuff

Comment: Hey ask for a useless dialog to comfirmed the user buy or not... For this stuff he didn't need ajax...

Comment: How can I protect my system from sql injections? I never heard of pdo before hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Just a little example:

```
function myFunction()
  {
   var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to buy this??!");
       if (r==true)
              {
                insert_data();
                }

     }

 function insert_data() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                        'url': 'your_page_with_php_code.php',
                        'data': {id_task : id,nuovo_task : task},
                        'dataType': 'html',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'success': function(html) {
                           //html is the html printed in you .php page
                            }
                        }
                });                     
     }
```

Hope this will help.
It is quiet simple.

Comment: So I need to make another page with my php in , and put it after the url: ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Use the 'data' field for _POST data.

Comment: I still don't get in 100% , So I get the part that the url is to direct the part it needs to be used on , but the _POST needs to be used on what? Because it needs to do : Ok --> buy it , Cancel --> Stay on the page and do nothing , but then I do need to adjust my page with the isset ,because the isset will still do it , even if you said cancel , dont I?